# Double integral smaller than single integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, definite-integrals

Is this inequality true?
$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{a}^{x} f^2(t) \, dt \, dx \leq \int_{0}^{1} f^2(t) \, dt$

I've seen something like this used in a solution, where instead of $f^2$ I had $f^{2p-2}+(f')^2$ and I didn't understand how they got there. If it helps, all i know about f is that it reaches 0 in at least 1 point and it is a C1 function on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $a \in [0,1]$ we have $$\int_a^x f(t)^2\mathrm{d}t \le \int_0^1 f(t)^2\mathrm{d}t$$
for all $x \in [0,1]$, so integrating both sides from $0$ to $1$ (with respect to $x$) gives the inequality.

Comment: Oh wow, it was really as simple as that. Thanks! :D